# Unanswered questions with no answers

Tags: support, answers, search, no-answers

I have a very simple request here to implement, if it doesn't already exist, a way to filter questions by number of answers. This would allow you to look for questions with no answers at all (not just questions that have no *accepted* or upvoted answers, like the unanswered questions tab).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already do this using `answers:0` in the search.

Here are all questions with no answers, ordered by newest:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0

And here are all questions tagged [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) with no answers, ordered by newest:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bsql-server%5d%20answers%3a0

And here are all questions containing the word `foo`, ordered by newest:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=foo%20answers%3a0

Comment: Nope, I didn't look at the links because I thought you were just affecting the URL itself and not typing it into the search bar. Please excuse my ignorance.